# Text mining - Data extraction from website

Tags: xml, r, scrape, httr

Can anyone please help to extract reviews and their Location from below link? I have successfully able to write code but not able to download both data(reviews and their location) in two separate columns in excel. I am new to R.

"http://www.subaruoutback.org/forums/104-gen-4-2010-2014/22586-440-watt-9-speaker-harman-kardon-premium-audio-system-sound-quality.html"

Code which i have used:

```
thepage = readLines('http://www.subaruoutback.org/forums/104-gen-4-2010- 
    2014/22586-440-watt-9-speaker-harman-kardon-premium-audio-system-sound-  
    quality.html')

#Location
grep('Location',thepage)
thepage[2738]

mypattern = '\t\t\t\t<div>Location: ([^<]*)</div>'
datalines = grep(mypattern,thepage[2738:length(thepage)],value=TRUE)
datalines

getexpr = function(s,g)substring(s,g,g+attr(g,'match.length')-1)
gg = gregexpr(mypattern,datalines)
matches = mapply(getexpr,datalines,gg)
result = gsub(mypattern,'\\1',matches)
result
names(result) = NULL
result[1:10]
class(result)

#Review data
library(XML)
library(httr)
raw2 <- htmlTreeParse(thepage, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
data <- pathApply(raw2,"//div[startswith(@id,'post_message')]",xmlValue)
data <- unlist(data)
data
class(data)

df=data.frame(result,data)

write.csv(df,"D:/Important files/R Practice/texts/output9.csv")

 My Expected output:![My expected output format][1]
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? `df=data.frame(result,data = gsub("[\n\t\r]", "", data)); write.csv2(df,tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")); shell.exec(tf)` looks good here. (I stripped control characters and took write.csv2, which uses a comma for the decimal point and a semicolon for the separator)

Comment: Hey..thanks its working for me. Can we please have our output in below format? One column for result(location) and another column for their corresponding data(review). Data(review) should be in one cell of same column.

Comment: @RonakKumar - Update your question accordingly. Also link you provided is broken at my end.

Comment: Please use this link: "http://www.subaruoutback.org/forums/104-gen-4-2010-2014/22586-440-watt-9-speaker-harman-kardon-premium-audio-system-sound-quality.html" or the link provided in my question.

Comment: @lukeA - After using your code, i have got the output. But i want data(review) output let say for one person in one column. Review of one person is getting splitted in different columns.

Comment: @lukeA - Can you please give a code so that we can wrap a long string of text("result" of one individual) within a cell? as of now, it is getting splited in different cells.

Comment: @RonakKumar I've got just 10 rows and two cells: result & data.

Comment: @lukeA yes i too got 10 rows, but data(feedback) is getting splited into many different columns depending upon the length of data(feedback). We need to wrap the data(feedback) in a single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with using `rvest` and `stringr`

```
library("rvest")
library("stringr")
url <- "http://www.subaruoutback.org/forums/104-gen-4-2010-2014/22586-440-watt-9-speaker-harman-kardon-premium-audio-system-sound-quality.html"
text <- url %>% 
          html() %>%  
          html_nodes(".main-column-text") %>% 
          html_text() %>% 
          str_replace_all("\\r|\\n|\\t", "") %>%
          str_trim()

loc <- url %>% 
         html() %>%  
         html_nodes(".main-column-picture") %>% 
         html_text() %>% 
         str_extract("Location:[(a-z),:; -(A-Z)]+")

df <- data.frame(text, loc, stringsAsFactors=F)
df <- df[text != "QuoteQuick Reply", ]
df <- df[!grepl("^Go to first new post", df$text), ]
```